# Postgresql with Outer Join to Get Nulls Included

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

New to databases.  I have a schema as follows:

```
Employee(**eid**, pname, age) 
Dept(**dname**, num_managers) / Dept = department
Dept_Wing(**wingno**, wing_name, dname) / Dept_Wing = which wing of department
Wing_Sub_Division(**dname**, **wingno**, **sub_div_no**) / Wing_Sub_Division = which sub-division of the wing 
On_Duty(**eid**, **dname**, **wingno**, sub_div_no)
```

I want to get the: dname, wingno, number on duty for that wing 
for each and all wings than have less than 15% employees on duty of the total number of employees (so this includes dept_wings with 0 employees on duty).

I tried

```
select w.wingo, od.wingo
from dept_wing w left outer join on_duty od on on w.wingo=od.wingno
```

just to get all the wings which have even no employees on duty, but I'm not able to even return those wings! Any is guidance appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting no results or an error message? I ask because your FROM clause specifies a join on the wingo columns but your schema calls these wingno (i.e. with an n).

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo on my part!  There's no such column as "wingo" so I fixed it to wingno

Comment: You are saying the query runs, but returns no rows? It should. Even too many at that.

Comment: Or are you getting an error? On the still misspelled wing[n]os for example or on the duplicate `on`.

Comment: I get the wings with employees on duty (so whatever matches between the 2 tables).  What I want is the wings with employees on duty AND the wings with 0 employees on duty...bc the on_duty table only lists wing numbers (wingno) for those with employees on duty...

Comment: But you outer join the duty table, so you should get *all* wings. Scroll in your result list. Or use an `ORDER BY` clause. They must be there.

Comment: As to your data model: `dname` + `wingno` is the Dept_Wing's primary key, yes? And you can have a `wingno` 1 both in department 'A' and 'B', which is why you need the `dname` in order to uniquely identify a wing, correct?

Comment: Yeah, I should've specified what the keys were, completely slipped my mind.  I've edited it such that the columns with ** ** are the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are working with composite keys; a department wing is identified by `dname` and `wingno`, so you have the pair in `Dept_Wing`, `Wing_Sub_Division`, and `On_Duty`. This makes this query quite simple.

Here is how to get the number of employees on duty per wing:

```
select dname, wingno, count(*)
from on_duty
group by dname, wingno
```

So the whole query is

```
select
  wing.dname, wing.wingno, coalesce(duty.cnt, 0) as employees_on_duty
from dept_wing wing
left join
(
  select dname, wingno, count(*) as cnt
  from on_duty
  group by dname, wingno
) duty on duty.dname = wing.dname and duty.wingno = wing.wingno
where coalesce(duty.cnt, 0) < 0.15 * (select count(*) from employee);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Trying to think this thru...in the first "from" statement...is that supposed to be "dept_wing wing"? I'm assuming you meant "dept_wing" correct?

Comment: `wing` is an alias. Use `w` if you prefer this.

Comment: Where does the < 15% condition factor in?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot that. I've updated my answer. 15% or 12%? Well, I've used 15%.

Comment: Woah, neat! You're right, I meant 15%.  It's gonna take me a while to chew through your solution but thanks a bunch!